# Chrome Extension and Content Security Policy and GWT RPC

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gwt-rpc, content-security-policy

I have chrome extension in that I am trying to use GWT RPC. Cant make it work. I compile my GWT code with <add-linker name="xsiframe" /> in my module xml file.  I am still getting following exceptions in js chrome console without any line numbers:

**Refused to execute JavaScript URL because of Content-Security-Policy.**

My manifest.json, ver.2is like this:

```
    "permissions": [
        "http://*/"
      ],

  "content_security_policy": "default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self'; object-        src 'self'; frame-src about:",

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "js-lib/",
    "js-code/",
    "compiled_gwt_code_from_gwt-war/"
  ]
```

Is there a know solution for this deployment? Or what is probably wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new CSP is bullshit. It deliberately cuts off functionality, and it doesn't allow overrides, even though developers know damn well what they're doing.

For now, revert to manifest v.1 in extension manifest.

```
 ...
 manifest_version: 1,
 ...
```

The spec should probably become less communist in the future.

Comment: Changing manifest version to 1 makes no change. Same errors still there.

Comment: What Chrome version are you running?

Comment: I am using ver. 19 on Windows.

Comment: Have you also commented the line with `content_security_policy`? I don't know, according to http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifestVersion.html it should work.

Comment: No, but then I thought about it and commented it out. Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: Just FYI, manifest_version:1 is being deprecated soon and extensions which rely on it will not be listed in the Chrome Web Store in about a year.

Comment: manifest_version:1 can't be used anymore, even in dev mode... Is there another way to get around this ?